# Logstash CSV parsing with XML as a field

Tags: xml, csv, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a CSV file that I am trying to parse with Logstash using the csv filter.
Unfortunately the source file contains a field that has a XML data - I am not sure if it technically a valid CSV file but don't have much of a choice at this time. 
Is there any way to either just drop the XML field for now or better yet, parse it in?

Source file example:
`audit_record_id|audit_state|audit_event|audit_reason|delta|service_name|audit_date
12345|NONE|LOGIN||<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <AuditedChangedData/>||2015-09-21 01:00:16.770
123457|SUCCESS|TRANSACTION|tran_transfers|<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <AuditedChangedData><Property name="interval_type"></Property>....</Final></Property></AuditedChangedData>|TRANSACTIONS|2015-09-21 01:49:43.697`

Logstash configuration:

```
        if [type] == "Audit" {

            if ([message] =~ "audit_record_id") {
                    drop {}
            }
            csv {
                    separator => ["|"]
                    columns => ["audit_record_id","audit_state","audit_event","audit_reason","delta","service_name","audit_date"]
            }
            mutate { remove_field => ["message"] }
            date { match => [ "audit_date", "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ] target => "audit_date" }
      }
    }
```

The error that I receive is:

`:exception=>#<CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.>`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the line is pipe-delimited, why are you using the kv{} filter?

Comment: Sorry - ignore the kv filter part, that was me trying to just remove the quotes from the XML fields.